# Calling PHPword third party libraries in Code Igniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-3, phpword

I have a problem with calling PHPWord library in Code Igniter, I already using PHPExcel and there are no problems everything goes smoothly.
But I have a problem with this PHPWord, because when I tried to use the same method to call the PHPExcel, it doesnt solve anything. I still seeing an error.

It's not like I don't search it on the google, I already searched it, but still, no one can solve my problem, I don't where is the problem.

So let me explain what is the problem.

> FYI: I using PHP 7.1.1

Because the PHP version, PHPWord got some errors that says a class named as a **String** that is known as variable, so because of that error, I changed it to **Strings** all of them that associated with that class.
After I changed it, I want to call the class with library file.

This is the file:

```
<?php if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');

require_once APPPATH.'/third_party/PHPWord/Autoloader.php';
    use PhpOffice\PhpWord\Autoloader as Autoloader;
    use PhpOffice\PhpWord\Settings as Settings;
    use PhpOffice\PhpWord\PhpWord as PhpWord;

/* I tried two different ways */
// class Word extends PhpWord {
//     public function __construct() { 
//         parent::__construct(); 
//     } 
// }

Autoloader::register();
Settings::loadConfig();
```

And this is the Controller code that calls the class.

```
$this->load->library('word');

$section = $this->word->createSection(array('orientation'=>'landscape'));
```

After I did that, it says **Non-existent class: Word**, I don't know anymore where is the problem, is it because I changed the class name? or it doesn't compatible with my CI version(3)?

Because I already tried different ways and still cannot solve this problem, can someone help me with this problem and show me what I did wrong? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tried with PHP7 but I found this Github repo which worked for me.

https://github.com/webeasystep/phpword_codeigniter

I just copied the application\third_party\PhpWord folder and application\library\PhpWord.php into the same locations in my project and then used some of the code from the controller provided, e.g...

```
public function test()
{
    $this->load->library('Phpword');

    $phpWord = new \PhpOffice\PhpWord\PhpWord();
    $phpWord->getCompatibility()->setOoxmlVersion(14);
    $phpWord->getCompatibility()->setOoxmlVersion(15);


    $filename = 'test.docx';
    // add style settings for the title and paragraph

    $section = $phpWord->addSection();
    $section->addText("Hello, world");
    $section->addTextBreak(1);
    $section->addText("It's cold outside.");

    $objWriter = \PhpOffice\PhpWord\IOFactory::createWriter($phpWord, 'Word2007');
    $objWriter->save($filename);
    // send results to browser to download
    header('Content-Description: File Transfer');
    header('Content-Type: application/octet-stream');
    header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename='.$filename);
    header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary');
    header('Expires: 0');
    header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0');
    header('Pragma: public');
    header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($filename));
    flush();
    readfile($filename);
    unlink($filename); // deletes the temporary file
    exit;
}
```

This works fine, I get a .docx when I hit my controller/test in a browser

Comment: Not working for PHP 7.1 . getting error "Cannot use PhpOffice\PhpWord\Shared\String as String because 'String' is a special class name"

Answer (score 0):

Following library is working smoothly for me for PHP 7 version without any error.

https://github.com/rifqisucahyo/CI_PHPWord

```
class Word extends PHPWord {
 public function __construct() {
   parent::__construct();
   $this->load->library('word');
 }

 function index() {
    require_once APPPATH."/third_party/PHPWord.php";
    $PHPWord = $this->word; // New Word Document
    $section = $PHPWord->createSection(); // New portrait section
    // Add text elements
    $section->addText('Hello World!');
    $section->addTextBreak(2);
    $section->addText('Mohammad Rifqi Sucahyo.', array('name'=>'Verdana', 'color'=>'006699'));
    $section->addTextBreak(2);
    $PHPWord->addFontStyle('rStyle', array('bold'=>true, 'italic'=>true, 'size'=>16));
    $PHPWord->addParagraphStyle('pStyle', array('align'=>'center', 'spaceAfter'=>100));
    // Save File / Download (Download dialog, prompt user to save or simply open it)
    $section->addText('Ini Adalah Demo PHPWord untuk CI', 'rStyle', 'pStyle');

    $filename='just_some_random_name.docx'; //save our document as this file name
    header('Content-Type: application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document'); //mime type
    header('Content-Disposition: attachment;filename="'.$filename.'"'); //tell browser what's the file name
    header('Cache-Control: max-age=0'); //no cache
    $objWriter = PHPWord_IOFactory::createWriter($PHPWord, 'Word2007');
    $objWriter->save('php://output');
 }

}
```